# Rebasing in Git (Fetch and then..?)

Tags: git, commit, pull, fetch

I have been working locally on a new computer to which I transferred all data from my old computer via external drive. I decided to try to rebase my work with what I have already on my server.

First I tried to commit and push but it was not possible to push due to some changes done on the server after I had copied the file to the new computer.

I then used Fetch in SmartGit so it fetched the server branch and the files I had been writing on my computer were removed. The local repository says < rebasing > in SmartGit and that 5 commits are pushable and that it is 1 commit behind. I understand that I need do some rebasing here but cannot really figure out what the next appropriate step is. Hopefully the files I had been working on are not lost? How should i proceed?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Im not familiar with Smartgit, however in bash git:

```
git fetch <upstream> <branch>
git pull --rebase <upstream> <brannch>
```

will basically put all your work OVER everything that the upstream branch is. It first rollback (which it announces) and then applies your commits over it.